# Making A File Copy itself under a random name

Tags: python

I am trying to make a code in python that creates a new file and then copies it under a randomly assigned new name, I have successfully programmed python to create a file and then to copy it under a new name, however, I cannot get it to randomly assign a name to the new file. Here is my current code.

```
import os
import random
import shutil
#makes directory called 'Yes'
os.makedirs('C:/Yes')
X=('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
#Generates random letters
A=random.choice(X)
B=random.choice(X)
C=random.choice(X)
D=random.choice(X)
E=random.choice(X)
F=random.choice(X)
#makes name of renamed directory
Y=('C:/',A,B,C,D,E,F)
#renames directory
os.rename('C:/Yes',Y)
```

It gives me the error message 
os.rename('C:/Yes', Y)
TypeError: illegal type for path parameter

Comment: `Y` isn't a string; maybe do `'C:/'+A+B+C+D+E+F` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Y=('C:/',A,B,C,D,E,F)
```

Is not a string, it's a tuple instead, which can't be passed into `os.rename`

What you need is:

```
Y=''.join(['C:/',A,B,C,D,E,F]) # returns a string without using '+'
```

Comment: note: you can pass a tuple to `str.join` —  any iterable of strings is fine

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain the original issue, that `Y` is a tuple when it should be a string. You can join the elements of the tuple into a string with the `str.join` method.

Also, you can create a list of random letters more succinctly:

```
import random
import string

letters = random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=6)
"".join(letters)
```

This will create a string like `'gtwycd'`, which you can join with `C:/`.

To join `C:/` and the letters, you should use `os.path.join` or `pathlib.Path`, like below:

```
import os
import pathlib
import random
import string

letters = random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=6)
letters_str = "".join(letters)
os.path.join("C:/", letters_str)
# or
pathlib.Path("C:/") / letters_str
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using os.path.join like that will result in an unqualified path e.g. `C:/hyudfs\subdir`. Better to use `WindowsPath` from `pathlib` or change the drive string to `C:\\``

Comment: @nicholishen - i edited my answer to demonstrate how to use `pathlib.Path` for this. i would prefer using `Path` than `WindowsPath`, as `Path` will default to `WindowsPath` on windows and something else on other systems.

Answer (score 1):

To create a random string for a filename it is easier to just use uuid.

```
import uuid
str(uuid.uuid4())
```

gives:

```
'122ba2ca-69d8-4425-b5e3-5305d31ad59f'
```

(or similar of course, you are guaranteed this is unique)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Y` is a tuple; you need it to be a string.

The `+` operator is used to concatenate strings together.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little change in your script to make it work:

```
import os
import random
import shutil
X=('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
#Generates random letters
A=random.choice(X)
B=random.choice(X)
C=random.choice(X)
D=random.choice(X)
E=random.choice(X)
F=random.choice(X)
#makes name of renamed directory
Y=os.path.join('C:/Yes',A,B,C,D,E,F)
os.makedirs(Y)
```

You need to place the path together with `os.path.join` and then create dirs with `makedirs` to create all the dirs at once.

Y is being created as a tuple in your code, an it should be a string. `os.path.join` is the function used to concatenate the directories in one path.